# parental jquery is not used by iframes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have my homepage that runs jquery in the head> tag by loading it from ajax google apis

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

it tried to use jquery functions in an iframe list.php -> head> tag:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug.  without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
setInterval(function() {
    $("#listts3").load("http://www.mydomain/list.php", "");
}, 60000);
});
```

but it returns me this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined list.php:153
(anonymous function)
```

it's possible that the iframe doesn't use the jquery parental source?
Have i load jquery again in the iframe too?!

Comment: iframes are basically separate pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it's possible that the iframe doesn't use the jquery parental source?

Yes. [That is how iframes work.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) They are almost completely separate from the page in which they are embedded.

> Have i load jquery again in the iframe too?!

Yes. JavaScript and CSS do not cross iframe boundaries (excepting JS in [very](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Scripting) [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent) [cases](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage)).